# AWS Elastic Beanstalk option_settings not applied

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a [Java SE app](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html) to [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/elastic-beanstalk/) and want to ensure that the `option_settings` specified in my `.ebextensions/otions.config` file are applied as described [in the](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-during.html#configuration-options-during-ebcli) [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-optionsettings.html). I want to adjust the ELB and ASG settings:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:policies
    option_name: ConnectionSettingIdleTimeout
    value: 120
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: InstanceType
    value: t2.nano
```

I include this file in the artifact I am deploying to beanstalk. I am deploying a app.zip file with the following structure:

```
$ unzip -l app.zip
...
       72  12-17-15 18:17   Procfile
 83199508  12-17-15 18:17   app.jar
        0  12-17-15 18:17   .ebextensions/
      209  12-17-15 18:17   .ebextensions/options.config
```

I am using the `eb` [CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html) to create/terminate/update my EBS app:

```
$ eb terminate
$ # .. create app.zip file
$ eb create
$ eb deploy
```

However, when I create the EBS environment and/or update it, **neither the ELB nor the ASG configuration get applied**. Is the file at the wrong place? Do you need to change the way I am deploying this to EBS to apply the config properly? My app it